# How to store and Retrieve images from the local device in android programmatically ?

Tags: android, image, gridview, path, android-arrayadapter

My task is to take pictures and uploading it in cloud storage, In upload screen I have two buttons one is "Upload" and other is "Park", 
i) if I select "Upload" it should upload the images on cloud.
ii) if I select "Park"  it should save the entire data into a activity with a button Load1.

What is Park ?

park should have the entire user data's stored previously

On clicking this load button I need to show the previously stored images in the thumbnail, eg. If I am taking 10 images I am showing those 10 images in the thumbnail as shown in below screenshot, while i m selecting the load it is showing 10th image for the three default images it is not showing all the 10 images which i have taken. How can I make it work properly?

This is my CameraActivity code where I am saving the images:

```
 private void saveAndShowImage(byte[] data) {

    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    //rotate the image by 90degree.
    bmp1 = RotateBitmap(bmp1, 90);
    bmp1 = Singleton.getResizedBitmap(bmp1);
    imageName = "img" + currentDateTimeString + ".png";
    saveImage(this, imageName, bmp1);
    LogEvent.Log(TAG,"bmp1"+bmp1);
    boolean isObjectReplaced = false;

    int size = 3;
    if(bitmapArray.size() < 3) {
        size = bitmapArray.size();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (bitmapArray.get(i).imageName == null) {

            bitmapArray.set(i, new ImageNote("", currentDateTimeString, imageName));
            isObjectReplaced = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isObjectReplaced) {
        bitmapArray.add(new ImageNote("", currentDateTimeString, imageName));
    }

    Log.d(currentDateTimeString, "ss");
    Log.i("imagesize", "ImageWidth = " + bmp1.getWidth() + "ImageHeight = " + bmp1.getHeight());

    CameraActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (imageCount > 2) {
                gv.scrollTo(convertDpToPixel(590 * bitmapArray.size()) + 10);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

//it is saving the image and show in the gridview .
private class ImageSaveAndShow extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    private byte[] data;

    public ImageSaveAndShow(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        saveAndShowImage(data);
        return true;
    }
}


public static void saveImage(Context context, String filename,
                             Bitmap bitmap) {

    File cacheDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

    File backgroundImagesDir = new File(cacheDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + "LoadProof");
    if (!backgroundImagesDir.isDirectory()) {
        backgroundImagesDir.mkdir();
        Log.i(TAG, "LoadProof Directory Created");
    }

    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = null;

    try {

        file = new File(backgroundImagesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);
        Log.i(TAG, "saved to " + file.toString());

        // Storing the path to show the previously stored image

        if(loadClickCount==1) {

            SharedPreferences prefernces = context.getSharedPreferences("parkload", Context.MODE_APPEND);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefernces.edit();
            editor.putString("Path", String.valueOf(file));
            editor.commit();
            String old = prefernces.getString("Path",null);
            LogEvent.Log(TAG,"llll" + "   " + old + "     " + path);

        }

        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        file = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "File Written");
        bitmap = null;
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

AdaperCode

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageNote> {
private final ArrayList<ImageNote> objects;
private Context context;
String TAG = "Adapter";
public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageNote> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_image, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivCampic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCampic);
        holder.ivDeletion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDeletion);
        holder.tvPos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number_camera);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_image, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivCampic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCampic);
        holder.ivDeletion = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDeletion);
        holder.tvPos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number_camera);
    }


    if (objects.get(pos).imageName == null && pos < 3 && park1==false) {

        holder.ivCampic.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
        holder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.tvPos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (park1 == true) {

        // Assigning previously stored path

        SharedPreferences prefernces = context.getSharedPreferences("parkload", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        String load1Path = prefernces.getString("Path", null);
        LogEvent.Log(TAG,"lllll"+ "   " + load1Path);

        String path = load1Path;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (bmp != null) {
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        holder.ivCampic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        holder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvPos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

        // Assigning path of the pictures from camera directly

        String path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/LoadProof/"
                + objects.get(pos).imageName;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (bmp != null) {
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        holder.ivCampic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        holder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvPos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    LogEvent.Log(TAG,"text1 /"+String.valueOf(pos + 1)+"pos "+pos);
    holder.tvPos.setText(String.valueOf(pos+1));
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

    holder.ivDeletion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            objects.remove(pos);
            CameraActivity.imageCount--;


            if (bitmapArray.size() < 3) {

                bitmapArray.add(new ImageNote("", null, null));
                finalHolder.ivCampic.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
                finalHolder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (pos == bitmapArray.size() - 1) {

                    //it is the last image which has been deleted when size()<=3.

                    finalHolder.ivCampic.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
                    finalHolder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.tvPos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {

                    //it is not the last image which has been deleted when size()<=3.

                    finalHolder.ivCampic.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
                    finalHolder.ivDeletion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            } else {

                // when bitmapArray.size()>3

                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private  class ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ivCampic;
    public ImageView ivDeletion;
    public TextView tvPos;
}
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overwriting the path in the shared preference, only the latest path can be retrieved. It will be better if you could store it as an array in a file. so you can retrieve the path using the array index and no overwriting will happen.